# Problem with Bash loop in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, loop, grass.script

I'm new to GRASS GIS and programming and I'm running into a lot of what I imagine are beginners problems and something similar to this has been asked before, but not In a way that I understand.

I'm trying to bash import tif. files and tried (from GRASS GIS 6 tutorial https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_6_Tutorial/Raster_data_management):

```
for file in `ls *.tif`
 do
  r.in.gdal input=$file output=${file%.tif}
done
```

but I get

```
File "<input>", line 1
    for file in `ls *.tif`
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since I'm new to programming world I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above, in accordance with the title of your question, refers to scripting in a bash shell. (**Not** python). If you would like more information on bash scripting, have a look at [this](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial) tutorial (referred from the GRASS bash scripting [wiki page](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell#GRASS_Batch_jobs)

If you want to work in python, then the language is quite different. For example, to loop thru a directory of *.tif files in python might go:

```
import os,glob
for tif_file in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    new_rast = os.path.splitext(tif_file)[0]  
    grass.run_command('r.in.gdal', input=tif_file, output=new_rast)
```

So, first choose your tools :-)

Comment: ok, thanks both of you, very helpful answers for a beginner, helped me towards a better understanding of these programming languages. I'm trying to use python for now, trying to figure all this out.

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax is:

```
for file in $(ls *.tif); do r.in.gdal input=$file output=${file%.tif}; done;
```

Where you gather the individual values provided by `ls` and iterate through them, so you have to put a variable sign(`$`) before the `ls` command and put it between brackets.

When you call for the `file` variable later, you can either call for `$file` as in the input parameter or call a function to it, like the stripping function with the braces. If you call it in a function, you have to put a semicolon after, because in bash, the semicolon signs the end of a function/command.

Comment: I still get an syntax error, only know it points at the $ sign.

Comment: What is the full code, you're getting the syntax error for? For me, typing the code above in the GRASS terminal works fine.

Comment: Well, i'm still trying to figure out what to put in the code, I haven't figured out what basic thing to put in a code, like what would precede this syntax. I just put the syntax in the python terminal in grass.

Comment: The proper syntax, for the first part of the loop command is: `for file in *.tif`. The `ls` command is neither needed nor correct, I think. For more read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching.