# How to import multiple TIFF files via r.in.gdal in GRASS GIS?

Tags: python, grass-gis, modis

I have a 18-year time series of the MODIS with temperature data, however there are more than 750 TIFF files.

How can I do to import all at once? Importing the files one by one is a very difficult task.

How do I do this using the function r.in.gdal in GRASS GIS?

Answer (score 1):

Yo would accomplish this with a loop. How to do that depends on your OS, and whatever scripting environment you're comfortable with. 
Here are some examples:

[GIS.Stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101561/how-to-process-multiple-images-in-grass-gis)

[StackExchange from several years ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70945/scripting-map-production-in-grass)

[Third example on StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116415/problem-with-bash-loop-in-grass-gis)

[Code example from "The GRASS Book"](https://grassbook.org/code-examples/code-examples-3rd-edition/)

(There are more...)

Give it a try, and post back with **specific details** if you are still having trouble.